# search in laravel database with live results

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I'm working with Laravel 5.4 and I have a list of users in admin panel I want to add search box in top of my users list to search them and I want to results be live (when typing words results shows) I guess should use Ajax for that(not sure!)

Let say this is my users list code:

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
  <td>{{ $user->first_name }}</td>
  <td>{{ $user->last_name }}</td>
  <td>{{ $user->username }}</td>
  <td>{{ $user->email }}</td>
@endforeach
```

How can I get that search to work with it?

Should I install any plugin or just use Vue.Js or ...?

Thanks.

Comment: @JohnDoe thanks man but if google was helping why would i publish my question here?!

Comment: @JohnDoe probably means this: https://www.google.bg/search?q=Laravel+autocomplete&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&ei=qco0Wev-FuOv8wfb94fwCQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you actually must use ajax technology for this ..
but only once .. let the angularJS or vue do the searching function ..
i actually wanted to post a snippet here but there's seems to be a bug .. so here's a [sample](http://embed.plnkr.co/j7vFicOMnyM8CiOfKLPj/) you might wanna see ..

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145408/discussion-between-robert-nicjoo-and-demonyowh

Answer (score 0):

You could use https://datatables.net/

Include in your html (if you're using gulp, use in your file who controls the dependencies)

```
    <table id="myTable">
        <thead>
            <th>First name</th>
            <th>Last name</th>
            <th>Username</th>
            <th>Email</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach($users as $user)
            <td> {{ $user->first_name }} </td>
            <td> {{ $user->last_name }} </td>
            <td> {{ $user->username}} </td>
            <td> {{ $user->email }} </td>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.15/css/dataTables.bootstrap.css" />

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.js">

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#myTable').DataTable();
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: I tried your way and found this https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables . I installed but confuse how to use it actually!